# html/css/js best practices

Tags: javascript, html, web, css, books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Are there any books or resources on html/css/js and web design best practices?
There are plenty books which just learn the basics - syntax and other stuff which is not quite difficult, but I can't find use cases, real examples, how professional desginers use them.

Comment: [Validating](http://validator.w3.org/) your markup, [checking](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your CSS, and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)ing (or something similar) really helps you conform to best practices. If you past all of the above tests, even if you don't know what "best practice" is, you're doing well.

Comment: This is certainly not a satisfactory answer, but best practices are often a little nebulous. There are accepted techniques, for certain, but "best practice" is highly dependent on the situation. Learn about and code for semantics (HTML), modularity (CSS and JS), and efficiency (all three, but mostly CSS and JS).

Comment: Seconded. Beware of Kool Aid.

Answer (score 4):

[HTML5 and CSS3 for the real world](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/htmlcss1/)

Is a very recent book on those topics.

As for actual modern best practices, they change so rapidly any book more then a year old is outdated.

However for JavaScript you can never go wrong with [The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)

I would personally advice you to use mentors and internet resources rather then books.

[The JS SO Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) does welcome high level language-agnostic web design questions or will at least redirect you somewhere useful and so does the PHP room.

[Comp lang JavaScript](http://www.fortybelow.ca/hosted/comp-lang-javascript/faq/) is also a solid resource of information and so is [MDN Learn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn)