# What should a web developer know about HTTP?

Tags: web-development, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should every programmer know about web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development)

I've heard rumblings on this site that web developers should be familiarize themselves with HTTP.

What aspects of HTTP is it beneficial to know as a web developer, and why?

**Update**: This is *not* an exact duplicate of This is not a duplicate of "What should every programmer know about web development?"  I am asking specifically about the *HTTP protocol*.  I am not using HTTP to mean web development in general.

Comment: The RFC is not all that big.  There's just two parts: requests and replies.  It's not clear what you mean by "aspect".  Can you provide examples or suggestions of "aspects" of HTTP?

Answer (score 10):

The most important aspect of HTTP to a web developer is that it is **stateless**. Every web developer should know this, as it means that if you want to maintain a state for your application, you'll have to do that in your application/on your platform.

You use it in a request/response manner and every web developer should know  and understand *at least* the basic http commands GET and POST.

Comment: And also understand when to use GET and when to use POST. (e.g. no POST for a search query, no GET for creating a new forum topic.)

Answer (score 7):

I would say **Everything**.

HTTP is by far the most important application level protocol. The entire Web lives within HTTP, and the more we progress toward service oriented architectures -- the more of HTTP will be exploited.

- Look at Google -- it's heavily HTTP based architecture. A simple search touches about 200 servers at Google and all of them communicate via HTTP.
- Some years ago verbs like PUT or DELETE were virtually futile -- but now every decent RESTful service uses them.
- Everybody knows ***caching*** is the best friend of scalability. How would you setup an efficient caching system without mastering HTTP caching infrastructure?
- HTTP is the most well understood protocol -- there is an entire eco-system around it. You can NOT take good advantage of that if you're only moderately familiar with HTTP.

So, in my opinion, every Web developer should have a thorough understanding of HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

Here would be my main ones:

- [Port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_number) - This is because you may have to run sites on different ports where you may find a rude shock that some ports are commonly used for some things.  For example, 80 is the standard web port, 443 is the standard SSL port, 25 is for SMTP, etc.
- [HTTP Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) - This would be about security in terms of protocols commonly used by people where it helps to know a little of what is going on under the surface.
- [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) - This can be useful just so that if you see a status code in Firebug or Fiddler you know what this or that means.

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) would have the more general data that could be useful though some of it may be common sense like a Request-response model and is stateless.