# Web based applications

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should every programmer know about web development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development)

Where do I start if I want to build a web based application? 
Books, tutorials, online resources. 
From a quick look at the web I can see that Html, Css and JavaScript should be the subjects to learn. Do you agree? What would you recommend to a professional C++ programmer?

Comment: @Anna Lear - the link is useful but would be overwhelming for a newcomer.

Comment: @GoodEnough Perhaps, but that's why it's canonical: we can't feasibly reask every question over when the answers to the older version become too complete.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is by reading one of those to learn about the basics of a web page (without application logic):

- [The Web Standards Project (WaSP)](http://www.webstandards.org/)
- [Web Standards Curriculum by Opera](http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/)

Then start investigating about web development frameworks and pick one that fits your way of thinking. Popular options are:

- [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)
- [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html)
- [a ton of PHP frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929644/best-php-framework-for-someone-who-has-never-used-one)

Note that there are many more options, but these seem to be the most popular.

Once you've chosen a framework (any will do, don't worry too much about choosing the best one), look at tutorials, there should be plenty about 'creating your first application'.

Once you're there, it should be fairly simple to find more information and figure out what you need to know in order to go further.

Good luck!